# asp.net store a cookie/session for checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I want to achieve that if I checked the checkbox, after reload the page, it's still checked (I don't have a value stored in the database).

The checkbox is

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server"  />
```

The event about checkbox change it

```
  Protected Sub cb1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb1.CheckedChanged
    Dim SE_cb1 As Boolean = Nothing
    SE_cb1 = If(cb1.Checked = True, 1, 0)
    Session("SE_cb1") = SE_cb1

End Sub
```

The page load event is

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If Not Session("SE_cb1") Is Nothing Then cb1.Checked = If(Session("SE_cb1") = 1, True, False)

    end sub
```

I wonder why is that after I reload/redirect the page, the checked checkbox still dropped the check?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried a If Not Page.IsPostBack Then in the Page_Load?

Comment: I tried that as well, still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

OK, when i change the load event to prerender, it seems OK now. Thanks for the help!

Handles Me.Load--> Handles Me.PreRender